# Problema con rellenar datos faltantes en array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tengo dos array, el `array_1` viene `0` al `23` y el `array_2` viene del `1` al `23`. Lo que quiero realizar es que si el `array_2` le falta un dato este lo rellene como corresponde.

El `array_2` tiene datos de `hora` y `temperatura`. También tengo otro `array_3` pero este ya viene con todos los datos del `0` al `23`:

```
const array_1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
const array_2 = [
    {"hora":1,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":2,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":3,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":4,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":5,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":6,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":7,"temperatura":10},
    {"hora":8,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":9,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":10,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":11,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":12,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":13,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":14,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":15,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":16,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":17,"temperatura":14},
    {"hora":18,"temperatura":14},
    {"hora":19,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":20,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":21,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":22,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":23,"temperatura":13}]

const valor_nuevo = []
for(let datos of array_1){
 for(let dat of array_2){
  if(datos == dat.hora){
   valor_nuevo.push(dat.temperatura)  
  }else{
   valor_nuevo.push(0)
  }
 }
}
```

Lo que realmente necesito es que el `array_2` se agregue un nuevo dato que seria el `{"hora":0,"temperatura":0}`. Esto lo uso para ChartJS, si tienen otra forma de hacerlo adámela saber, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Daniel, faltaría que agregues el código que has intentado. No importa si tu código no funciona, es necesario que demuestres que algo has intentado. Utiliza la opción [edit] para agregarlo en tu pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: @Marcos como dijo amigo aqui la edicion, pero borre el codigo porque me daba mal los valores

Comment: ¿El `array_2` siempre viene ordenado por `hora` ascendente? Si es así, entonces existen una solución más eficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo...quieres crear una especie de `fill` para tu serie. Las bases de datos que manejan "TimeSeries" lo hacen automaticamente, supongo que no es tu caso.

Yo crearia un `Array` de 0 a 23, le haría un map buscando en `array_2` si existe la hora, de no ser así colocaría un valor `default`

```js
let array_2 = [   
    {"hora":1,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":2,"temperatura":13}];
    

let array_completo = Array
    .from({ length: 24 }, (v, i) => i)
    .map( i => array_2.find(a=> a.hora==i) || {"hora":i,"temperatura":0});

console.log(array_completo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que primero deberias buscar si la posicion existe con la hora correspondiente es decir la hora 0 deberia ser la primera posicion, si es el caso espero te ayude lo siguiente:

```js
const array_1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
const array_2 = [
    {"hora":1,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":2,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":3,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":4,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":5,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":6,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":7,"temperatura":10},
    {"hora":8,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":9,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":10,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":11,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":12,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":13,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":14,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":15,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":16,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":17,"temperatura":14},
    {"hora":18,"temperatura":14},
    {"hora":19,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":20,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":21,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":22,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":23,"temperatura":13}
]


array_1.forEach((item, index) => {
  const hour = index;
  const getHour = array_2.find(item => item.hora == hour)
  if (!getHour) {
    array_2.unshift({"hora": hour, "temperatura": hour})
  }
})

console.log(array_2)
```

Espero que ayude...

Comment: gracias, me esta hacercando mucho mas a la respuesta, solo me falta ver que si falta un dato entre medio de toda la array_2 la agrege justo despues donde falta es decir si falta la hora 21 que agrege 0 en temperatura en la hora 21 justo despues de la hora 20 :) , pero me ayudaste bastante :)

Comment: Si falta la hora 15, esto va a añadir una temperatura de 15 a esa hora, y no de 0, como creo que debiera ser.

Answer (score 1):

gracias a la ayuda del amigo @alfalexDev pude resolver el problema aqui solucionado con mas datos faltantes, muchas gracias :)

```js
const array_1 =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
    
    
      const data_2 = []
      let array_2 = [{"hora":1,"temperatura":16},{"hora":2,"temperatura":16},{"hora":3,"temperatura":16},{"hora":4,"temperatura":17},{"hora":5,"temperatura":17},{"hora":6,"temperatura":17},{"hora":7,"temperatura":17},{"hora":8,"temperatura":18},{"hora":9,"temperatura":18},{"hora":10,"temperatura":18},{"hora":11,"temperatura":19},{"hora":12,"temperatura":19},{"hora":13,"temperatura":19},{"hora":14,"temperatura":20},{"hora":15,"temperatura":20},{"hora":16,"temperatura":22},{"hora":17,"temperatura":22},{"hora":18,"temperatura":21},{"hora":19,"temperatura":20},{"hora":20,"temperatura":20},{"hora":22,"temperatura":19},{"hora":23,"temperatura":19}]

      array_1.forEach((item, index) => {
        const hour = index;
        const getHour = array_2.find(item => item.hora == hour)
        if (!getHour) {
          data_2.push(0)
        }else{
          data_2.push(getHour.temperatura)
        }
      })
console.log(data_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
let array_2 = [   
    {"hora":1,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":2,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":3,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":4,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":5,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":6,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":7,"temperatura":10},
    {"hora":8,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":9,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":10,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":11,"temperatura":11},
    {"hora":12,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":13,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":14,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":15,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":16,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":17,"temperatura":14},
    {"hora":18,"temperatura":14},
    {"hora":19,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":20,"temperatura":13},
    {"hora":21,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":22,"temperatura":12},
    {"hora":23,"temperatura":13}
];      
   // instancias los valores
let hora = 90;
let temp = 54;
   // creas el conjunto
let valores = { hora : hora, temperatura : temp };
   // lo agregas al array
array_2.push(
  valores
);

console.log(array_2);
```